# Shift several parts inside one dataframe in pandas with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, shift

I have a dataframe as below. For simpicity, it has columns A, B, Correctly Shifted(what I want to get) and Incorrectly Shifted (what I have now). I want to shift values in column 'A' based on condition in column 'B'. If I will use `pd.DataFrame.shift(1)` then it shifts the whole column by 1. But I want to shift using a kind of moving window i.e. shift several parts inside one dataframe. For example, I want to shift all rows in column 'A' by 1 based on values in column 'B' i.e. shift all rows with condition 'aaa', then shift all rows with condition 'bbb' and all rows with condition 'ccc' etc. In column 'Correctly Shifted' is what I want and in column 'Incorrectly Shifted' is what I get if just use shift method in pandas. What is the best approach to solve it?

| A | B | Correctly Shifted | Incorrectly Shifted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | aaa | nan | nan |
| 110 | aaa | 100 | 100 |
| 120 | aaa | 110 | 110 |
| 100 | bbb | nan | 120 |
| 110 | bbb | 100 | 100 |
| 120 | bbb | 110 | 110 |
| 100 | ccc | nan | 120 |
| 110 | ccc | 100 | 100 |
| 120 | ccc | 110 | 110 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["My Shift"] = df.groupby("B")["A"].shift()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     A    B  Correctly Shifted  Incorrectly Shifted  My Shift
0  100  aaa                NaN                  NaN       NaN
1  110  aaa              100.0                100.0     100.0
2  120  aaa              110.0                110.0     110.0
3  100  bbb                NaN                120.0       NaN
4  110  bbb              100.0                100.0     100.0
5  120  bbb              110.0                110.0     110.0
6  100  ccc                NaN                120.0       NaN
7  110  ccc              100.0                100.0     100.0
8  120  ccc              110.0                110.0     110.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is just that simple ))

Answer (score 1):

Try using `groupby` with `shift`:

```
df['A'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].shift()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       A    B
0    NaN  aaa
1  100.0  aaa
2  110.0  aaa
3    NaN  bbb
4  100.0  bbb
5  110.0  bbb
6    NaN  ccc
7  100.0  ccc
8  110.0  ccc
```